# Using a loop to continue or break the program if condition is met

Tags: python

I have started fiddling with python today for the first time in my life and I decided to make some sort of a lottery "game" where there's a pre-set list of registered users i.e. "players" that will be subject to validation by using the "player" variable. How can I use a loop to use the player variable input and search if it exists in the list players?
Probably this is a very stupid question, but am curious how to do it or if there is another better/more faster way I would appreciate someone enlightening me. Thank you:

```
lucky_numbers = [4, 8, 15, 17, 23, 42]
players = ["Kevin", "Stacey", "Jim", "Monica", "Donnie"]

player = input("Please enter your name: ")
if player in players:
    print(f"Ok {player}, move on..")
else:
    print(f"Uh oh, you are not on the players list!")

input_numbers = list(map(int, input("Enter 6 lucky numbers: ").split()))
if input_numbers == lucky_numbers:
    print("Congratulations! YOU WON!")
else:
    print("Sorry. You guessed wrong!")
```

Comment: You’ve put “loop” in the title ... which part of this code do you think currently involves a loop?  (This is a hint ...)

Comment: My suggestion is that you take a few steps back and look over the basic statements and their terminology again. There's no such thing as an "if loop". But it seems like you want is an *actual* loop, to ask the player name over and over until it's correct and then end the loop (using and `if` *condition* to **`break`** the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I read it several times, but I still don't quite understand what you mean.

Do you want users to enter the name repeatedly until the name is in the list? Once the name is in the list is allowed to proceed to the next stage?

```
lucky_numbers = [4, 8, 15, 17, 23, 42]
players = ["Kevin", "Stacey", "Jim", "Monica", "Donnie"]

is_login_success = False

while True:
    name = input("Please enter your name or enter `Exit` to exit game\n> ").capitalize().strip() 

    if name == "Exit":
        is_login_success = False
        print("Bye bye! Hope see you soon.")
        break
    elif name in players:
        is_login_success = True
        print(f"Ok {name}, move on..")
        break
    else:
        print("Uh oh, you are not on the players list!")
    
    print()


if is_login_success:
    # play game
```

In addition, make some suggestions about the game:

1. Prompt user for  number range of lottery and check input
2. Is your winning condition to enter the same number in the same order?  If only the same number is required, there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfect and I actually learned how to use the while loop as well as if and elif!
1. This is my next step to create a more advanced lottery game with randomly-generated number(s) and to also give the user a hint in what range that number(s) is.
2. Same number and same order - I tested it and it works as intended

Answer (score 0):

The error is in using the line
`player = print(input("Please enter your name: "))`
The player variable is not assigned if you print it.

should be
`player = input("Please enter your name: ")`
instead.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I don't know why everyone is voting me down I simply asked for help, am I supposed to be knowledgeable about things I am yet trying to learn?

Comment: I think your post title is not very accurate. Your code doesn't really contain a loop.

Comment: thank you. I fixed the title and edited my post. I am sorry for the confusion and my stupidity

Comment: Hey man its alright! don't have to beat yourself up about it. Anyways if the question is resolved you should mark it as answered.